# store array of objects in cookie, pure javascript, no jquery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store array of object inside cookie.

Without using jQuery or angular.

```
function setCook (name,value) {
  var cookie = [name, '=', JSON.stringify(value)].join('');
  document.cookie = cookie;
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of this object and maybe show what your expected output should be? Thank you.

Comment: *"I am trying to store array of object inside cookie"* Are you really going to use the objects on the **server**? If not, cookies are a poor choice. Use web storage, so you don't bloat requests to your server, and because the API is **dramatically** better.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any aspect of the code that you posted that is specific to jQuery or angular...

Comment: Noup, I am just trying to use it on my localhost. For example: const arr = [{"id":"1", "name":"nec"},{"id":"2", "name":"nec2"},{"id":"3", "name":"nec3"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `JSON.parse` your return:

https://repl.it/KKoF

```
function setCook(name, value) {
    var cookie = [
        name,
        '=',
        JSON.stringify(value)
    ].join('');
    document.cookie = cookie;
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return JSON.parse(
                c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length)
            );
        }
    }
    return null;
}

setCook('foo', `[
    {
        "qux": "boz"
    },
    {
        "baz": "zot"
    }
]`);
let obj = readCookie('foo');

console.log(obj);

/*
[
    {
        "qux": "boz"
    },
    {
        "baz": "zot"
    }
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this in the local file system and not on a server?
Cookies are not set when browsing using the file:/// protocol, depending on the browser.

Comment: please post this as a comment, as it is not a complete answer